# Stop the multiple display of an element in VueJS - Fancybox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fancybox, lightbox

I am looking for how to correctly integrate `fancybox` on a Vuejs carousel image gallery. But somehow i don't know, I get a display of multiple image items (actually all images in my array) from carousel to swipe instead of only displaying the chosen item in the carousel?
Thumbails display fine.

Here is my html code

```
  <div class="fancybox" data-fancybox="gallery" 
    v-for="(image, index) in images"
    :key="index"
    :href="image">
  <!-- <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox="gallery" :href="currentImage"> -->
    <img id="featured" :src="currentImage" alt="">
  </div>

  <div id="slide-wrapper">
    <img id="slideLeft" class="arrow" src="./images/arrow-left.png" alt="">
    <div id="slider">
      <img v-for="(image, index) in images" :src="image" alt="" :key="index"
        :class="['thumbnail', (activeImage == index) ? 'active' : '']" @click="activateImage(index)">
    </div>
    <img id="slideRight" class="arrow" src="./images/arrow-right.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    images: [
      './images/lordea-home-01-min.jpg',
      './images/lordea-home-02-min.jpg',
      './images/lordea-home-03-min.jpg',
      './images/lordea-home-04-min.jpg',
      './images/lordea-home-05-min.jpg',
      './images/lordea-home-06-min.jpg',
      './images/lordea-home-07-min.jpg',
      './images/lordea-home-08-min.jpg',
      './images/cam-house-01.jpg',
      './images/cam-house-02.jpg',
    ],
    activeImage: 0
  },
  
  computed: {
      currentImage() {
          return this.images[this.activeImage];
      }
  },
  methods: {
      // nextImage() {
      //     var active = this.activeImage + 1;
      //     if(active >= this.images.length) {
      //         active = 0;
      //     }
      //     this.activateImage(active);
      // },
      // prevImage() {
      //     var active = this.activeImage - 1;
      //     if(active < 0) {
      //         active = this.images.length - 1;
      //     }
      //     this.activateImage(active);
      // },
      activateImage(imageIndex) {
          this.activeImage = imageIndex;
      }
  },
  mounted() {

    let thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')
    
    let activeImages = document.getElementsByClassName('active')

    for (var i=0; i < thumbnails.length; i++ ) {

      thumbnails[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        // console.log(activeImages)

        if (activeImages.length > 0) {
          activeImages[0].classList.remove('active')
        }

        this.classList.add('active')
        document.getElementById('featured').src = this.src
      })
    }

    let buttonRight = document.getElementById ('slideRight');
    let buttonLeft = document.getElementById ('slideLeft');

    buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
      document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft -= 400
    })

    buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
      document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft += 400
    }),


    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".fancybox").fancybox(
        {
          infobar: false,
          buttons: [
            "zoom",
            "share",
            "slideShow",
            "fullScreen",
            "download",
            "thumbs",
            "close"
          ]
        }
      );
    });
    
    // $(".fancybox").fancybox ({
    //   infobar: false,
    //   buttons: [
    //     "zoom",
    //     "share",
    //     "slideShow",
    //     "fullScreen",
    //     "download",
    //     "thumbs",
    //     "close"
    //   ]
    // });
  },
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know FancyBox but is it a Jquery component?

Do you really have to integrate FancyBox?

I'd suggest you to create your own carrousel, you seem to have the correct logic to do it

Comment: This is not mandatory, but I find this library very attractive and also effective for displaying images in mode ("zoom", "share", "slideShow", "fullScreen", "download", "thumbs", "close"). Also, it would allow me to also learn how to integrate a lightbox in Vuejs, because I see that there are not many tutorials on this mixture of technologies. It might also help people like me who have had blockages in the past.
NB: yes, fancybox is jquery.

Comment: I'm am not a web development expert, but I don't think it's a good idea to mix JQuery and VueJS (maybe I'm horribly wrong)
I'd advise you to browse some Vuejs Carrousel components, you can find plenty online ;)

Comment: Ok I see. Do you have examples on the net, codepen or other on which I could be inspired? By the way i found many example who mix the two techs, but there were normal image gallery, but not carousel.

Comment: Since JQuery is more a library, and VueJS a Framework, they can both work together but maybe sometimes there are some conflicts, I honestly don't really know :p
You can browse this : https://vuejsexamples.com/tag/carousel/
These are components you can use and customize for your needs ;)